# Why does discord-py-slash-command pip package keep uninstalling itself?

Tags: pip, discord, package, discord.py, replit

Ever single time I open my code to test or edit it (I'm using repl.it btw) everything is fine running but discord.py slash commands just uninstall itself **EVERY TIME** I open the repl. its just annoying having to type "pip install discord-py-slash-commands" in the shell/terminal **EVERY TIME** I open my code. does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Install it using the packages section towards the left-hand side.